# Cant find the right widget combination, if it exists

Tags: flutter, widget

I have an Image (which is a map), that I want to always fill its container, but keeping its aspect ratio.

I put it inside an InteractiveViewer, so it can be zoomed and panned.

When the interactiveviewer zoom level is minimum(1) the whole width of the image must fit the container, and if the height does not fit, It should be possible to pan.

I tried many combinations of widgets, but could not find the right one for this behavior.

Can anyone with more flutter experience help?

Best Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by using constrained=false in the InteractiveViewer widget